# Problem with ROS Navigation Package (IMU GPS)

Tags: ekf, odometry, ros-kinetic, navsat-transform-node, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the objective of collecting laser data using a tripod and moving the tripod and I am using a Mavros ArduPilot board on the top of that tripod so that I can fuse the GPS and IMU.
Initially, I have created a simple *.urdf* file, where I have the laser (*laser_base*) approximately 1m above the *base_link*.

To fuse the IMU and GPS, my launch file is as follows:

```
<arg name="fcu_url" default="/dev/ttyUSB1:57600" />
(...)
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_local" clear_params="true">
  <param name="frequency" value="10 "/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>

  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom_combined"/>

  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/odom/out"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="/mavros/imu/data"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, true,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false,  false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                 false, false, false,       <!-- roll, pitch, yaw -->
                                 true, true, true,           <!-- dx, dy, dz2 -->
                                 true, true, true,           <!-- droll, dpitch, dyaw -->
                                 false, false, false]</rosparam> <!-- dx2, dy2, dz2 -->

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/> <!-- this was false -->
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>
  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>
  <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

  <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odom/out"/>
</node>

<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true" output="screen">

    <param name="frequency" value="20"/>
    <param name="delay" value="3"/>
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="false"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>

    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/mavros/global_position/raw/fix"/>
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/mavros/imu/data"/>
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odom/out" />

</node>

<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
</node>
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find ODpkg)/description/tripod.urdf" />
<node name="modelvisualization" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen"/>
```

So, navsat_transform_node receives the IMU from the ekf_localization_node and produces the odometry that will be used by ekf_localization_node, which results in a closed loop, as stated [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/).

Also, I have defined the world frame the same as the odom frame, as stated in the [Wiki](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/configuring_robot_localization.html).

As the odom is being produced by the gps, in odom_config, I have only defined x, y and z as true. Also, if on imu_config, I define either roll, Pitch, yaw, dx2, dy2 or dz2 as true, the base_link frame starts moving away from odom_frame infinitely and I don't know why.

So, to sum up, I wan't to move the tripod and keep recording laser data, so I want to notice any inclination or change in the direction of the tripod, as well as x, y, z changes. As it is right now, the distance between odom and base_link remains the same, no matter if I move the tripod. On the other hand, the joint, between laser_base and base_link (the "tripod") changes its orientation, but it starts getting an offset and sometimes gets completely wrong for no apparent reason.

A snippet of the IMU topic from the ArduPilot (/mavros/imu/data) is shown below:

```
header: 
  seq: 61
  stamp: 
    secs: 1533685811
    nsecs: 564266624
  frame_id: "base_link"
orientation: 
x: -0.00348900489561
y: -0.019581376355
z: -0.758538467474
w: 0.651324642484
orientation_covariance: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.00158514082432
  y: -0.00135391950607
  z: 0.00221287831664
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.2184696791468346e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2184696791468346e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2184696791468346e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0392266
  z: 9.83606995
linear_acceleration_covariance: [8.999999999999999e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.999999999999999e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.999999999999999e-08]
```

And the GPS topic (mavros/global_position/raw/fix):

```
header: (...)
frame_id: "base_link"
status: 
  status: -1
  service: 1
latitude: 38.6639703
longitude: -9.2055322
altitude: 132.121468393
position_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
position_covariance_type: 0
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong, namely on the imu_config? Shouldn't I be able to also set roll pitch yaw and the linear accelerations to true? Also, why is the base_link not moving when I move the tripod, considering it is taking the odom from the gps into consideration?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299959/problem-with-ros-navigation-package-(imu-gps)/) by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your EKF node config, your gps odometry topic name looks incorrect. It should be the output coming from your `navsat_transform_node` (which by default is `odometry/gps`). Also, not critical, but in your imu config you are fusing x/y/z velocities which aren't published by your imu.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-08**:
So, in my IMU config, should I be fusing the first two rows; the angular velocity and acceleration?

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-08**:
According to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/), doesnt the output of navsat defaults to *odom/filtered* (which I am then remapping to */odom/out*)?

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-08-08**:
For your IMU, the only valid rows to fuse are [2,4,5] which correspond to roll-pitch-yaw, roll dot-pitch dot-yaw dot, and accel x, accel y, accel z. My advice would be to start with just fusing roll-pitch-yaw and then add the others and compare performance.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-08-08**:
The statement Tom made "The odometry input to...output (it defaults to odometry/filtered)." is saying that the default **input** odom topic for navsat_transform is odometry/filtered, which is the default output of the EKF. But the default **output** of navsat_transform is odometry/gps

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-09**:
Thank you very much for your answer and tips.
It seems to be stable so now, but if I move the ArduPilot board, nothing happens, which I assume is because the gps coordinates are not changing. Tomorrow I'll go outside to test it better. Nevertheless, I will accept your answer.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-09**:
One thing that is bothering me now, is that with rqt_graph, the navsat_transform_node is not receiving any IMU topic, as it should.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-09**:
Also, if I set  accel x, accel y, accel z on IMU config to true, the base_link starts getting away from odom infinitely.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-08-09**:
navsat_transform_node only needs one imu message to initiate the utm->map frame TF, so it could be dropping the connection once it's publishing that TF. Regarding accelerations: does this happen even when you're receiving good gps?

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-09**:
Thank you. Might be. I will test outdoor in a couple of hours and will give feedback. Although it is not behaving bad, just a little slow, which is related to the Mavros topics' publish rate and not with the robot localization package.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-11**:
Sorry for the delay. Sill not working properly. Went outside to test today, but the x,y,z are not changing, although the GPS is presenting different values in its topic.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-08-11**:
Can you record & upload a bag file? Would make it easier to troubleshoot.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-11**:
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M2MFGphi7RlgL0C9nhJLVwJTc55kpS05/view?usp=sharing) it is. I created it when walking around with the ArduPilot board. The recorded topics are the gps and IMU ones (/mavros/imu/data and /mavros/global_position/raw/fix)

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-11**:
I have also created a [new question](https://answers.ros.org/question/300345/robot-localization-package-transform-from-base_link-to-odom-was-unavailable-for-the-time-requested-using-latest-instead-imugps/) with the current error it is showing.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-08-11**:
And I have created a [ros bag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ak7llCgtoWKseN6uswIcInIN5MbLBjCd/view?usp=sharing), where I am running the ekf and navsat_transform_node, and recorded all topics.